# Passing arguments to a Backbone.View's constructor

Tags: backbone.js

I create a Backbone View

```
App.MyView = Backbone.View.extend({...});
```

then instance it like

```
new App.MyView();
```

but if my object needs some initial values i

```
new App.MyView({name:"Beautiful"});
```

I then would access this options from `MyView` like that

```
App.MyView= Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log(this.options.name);
    }
});
```

This works good, however is not a self-explanatory object: i have to know before hand the need of passing in the initial values in a literal way `({this.name:"Beautiful"})` in order to make `MyView` work..

How can i pass in arguments like `initialize(name)` or something like that to make it clear that the values are needed in the View?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript functions don't have a defined number of arguments, so basically, you can't.
Writing:

```
function(name) {...}
```

is simply a shortcut for:

```
function() {
  var name = arguments[0];
  ...
}
```

You could eventually throw an error is your argument is undefined:

```
function(name) {
  if(typeof name === 'undefined') throw 'Error: missing argument';
  ...
}
```

But yeah, other than that, you can't force the use of an argument.

**Edit:**
If you're problem is just clarity, you cannot do that either I fear.

**Edit2:**
Well, you could if you really want to, but I'd really avoid walking those paths.